Can't use sed when using ssh with ms powershell to linux host
This is working in linux
sed "s/#\?\(PasswordAuthentication\s*\).*$/\1 no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config; 
But in MS Powershell in windows when I using
pwsh -c ssh root@161.97.108.95 -p 22 sed "s/#\?\(PasswordAuthentication\s*\).*$/\1 no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
I get following error
sed: -e expression #1, char 35: unterminated `s' command
Before I fix encoding issue in powershell so \1 look right. So for now I can't solve this.
$OutputEncoding = [Console]::InputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding
BodyName          : utf-8 
EncodingName      : Unicode (UTF-8) 
HeaderName        : utf-8 
WebName           : utf-8 
WindowsCodePage   : 1200 
IsBrowserDisplay  : True 
IsBrowserSave     : True 
IsMailNewsDisplay : True 
IsMailNewsSave    : True 
IsSingleByte      : False 
EncoderFallback   : System.Text.EncoderReplacementFallback 
DecoderFallback   : System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback 
IsReadOnly        : True 
CodePage          : 65001 
Edit more info

Is ssh in powershell th issue?
I see the command is changed in debug info


The error says '-e' option is failing.  You have a dollar sign in the sed expression which is causing the issue.  Replace the double quotes with single quotes so the dollar sign is treat as a character instead of the variable name.  sed can use any character as the start/end of a string.  So you can use angle brackets instead of quotes.  But here you must use single quotes so PS doesn't substitute the dollar sign.

@jdweng, while it's true that one must be mindful of interpretation of $ by PowerShell in "..." strings, in the case at hand it is not a problem, because a $ not followed by a subexpression or variable name is kept as-is. Thus, using '...' doesn't make a difference in this case, because "s/#\?\(PasswordAuthentication\s*\).*$/\1 no/" -eq 's/#\?\(PasswordAuthentication\s*\).*$/\1 no/' is $true

@mklement0 : I think you are wrong and OP should replace the double quotes with single quotes.  With double quotes people are always going to question the dollar sign and there is no harm in changing the double quotes to single quotes.

@jdweng, yes, using single quotes is unquestionably preferable if string expansion (interpolation) should be precluded, as implied by my previous comment. My point was: doing so doesn't make a difference in this particular case, so it isn't a solution. In other words: your comment should have been an aside, clearly stated as such, instead of pretending to be a solution.

@mklement0
My exactly output
PowerShell 7.4.3
PS C:\Users\Tirsvad> ssh root@161.97.108.95 -p 22 sed "s/#?(UsePAM\s*).*$/\1 no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command
PS C:\Users\Tirsvad> ssh root@161.97.108.95 -p 22 sed 's/#?(UsePAM\s*).*$/\1 no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config;
sed: -e expression #1, char 19: unterminated `s' command

You need to protect backslashes from both the local and the remote shell. Try adding single quotes around sed -e "s/.../" filename (and isn't the final semicolon unnecessary?)



It seems that ssh isn't capable of relaying arbitrary commands with separate arguments that contain \ characters to the remote shell, and simply escaping \ as \\ also does not work.

The solution is to pass the entire sed command line as a single argument to ssh:


# From PowerShell:
# Note the use of '...''...''...'
ssh root@161.97.108.95 -p 22 'sed ''s/#\?\(UsePAM\s*\).*$/\1 no/'' /etc/ssh/sshd_config'

Note:

Because PowerShell itself interpolates $-prefixed tokens inside "..." (expandable strings), it is better to use '...' (verbatim strings).

Unlike in POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, you can directly embed ' characters inside '...' by escaping them as '', as shown above.


In cases where you do need up-front string interpolation by PowerShell, be sure to escape any pass-through $ characters as `$, i.e. using the so-called backtick, PowerShell's escape character.

Note that \ has no special meaning in PowerShell, whereas it functions as the escape character in POSIX-compatible shells, for instance.

As an aside: $ chars. that aren't followed by an identifier (e.g., $foo) or  start a subexpression (e.g., $(1 + 2)) are left untouched, so there is no strict need to `-escape them, though it's probably better to do so for conceptual reasons; e.g., "5$/" is treated the same as "5`$/" by PowerShell and yields verbatim 5$/ ($ sign retained).
The same applies analogously to POSIX-compatible shells (except that escaping $ requires \$ there).



Your question shows an attempt to call ssh via pwsh -c, i.e. via pwsh, the PowerShell (Core) 7 CLI, which isn't necessary: just invoke ssh directly, as shown above.

If you were to call directly from cmd.exe, you'd use "..." for enclosing the sed command line as a whole (cmd.exe only recognizes double-quoting, and doesn't interpret $), and just '...' for the embedded sed script.




Calling your command from Python, via subprocess.run():

As noted, there is no need to call via the PowerShell CLI.

From Python, you have to option to call ssh directly, without involvement of a shell (be it PowerShell or cmd.exe).

On Windows only, you may still pass a whole command line to execute, in which case the quoting rules are in essence the same as in cmd.exe: only double-quoting ("...") is recognized.

Quoting in the case at hand gets tricky, because of the nested quoting that is necessary: embedded "..." quoting around the pass-through sed command, and, inside that, '...' quoting around the sed script. Additionally, the \ characters should be preserved as-is.

The simplest solution is to use a raw, triple-quoted string literal, r'''...''', inside of which ', ", and \ can all be embedded unescaped.


Therefore:
import subprocess

# Note: Shell-less invocation (`shell=False` is implied).
#       Passing a whole command line as a single string in a shell-less
#       invocation is supported on Windows only.
subprocess.run(
  r'''ssh root@161.97.108.95 -v -p 22 "sed 's/#\?\(UsePAM\s*\).*$/\1 no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"''', 
  encoding="utf-8"
)


Thanks for the detailed explanation.
Now I only have one issue back and that in my python script to use subprocess.run(#The command#) and get the same result

Glad to hear it helped, @Tirsvad. As for Python: try "..." quoting around the whole sed command line: subprocss.run('ssh root@161.97.108.95 -p 22 "sed 's/#\?\(UsePAM\s*\).*$/\1 no/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config"). If that doesn't help, I suggest creating a new question post focused just on this problem.

Found to solution for Python
#test.py import subprocess cmd = r"pwsh -Command ssh root@161.97.108.95 -v -p 22 'sed '\"'s/#\?\(UsePAM\s*\).*$/\1 no/'\"' /etc/ssh/sshd_config'" subprocess.run(cmd.replace('\\\\', '\\'), encoding="utf-8")

Glad to hear it, @Tirsvad. Indeed, in my since-deleted comment I used regular Python string literals and neglected to escape the \ characters in them as \\. Using a raw string literal is indeed preferable, and its triple-quoted form (r'''...''') allows you to also embed ' and " unescaped, which enables a simpler solution that neither requires calling via pwsh -Command nor post-processing of the string - please see my update.
